# How can I connect to an RDS DB from a Lambda function?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm having trouble trying connecting to a public RDS instance (MySQL) that I have set up.
I've tested my Lambda code locally (laptop) and it can connect to the MySQL instance and add rows to a table.  However, when I run the code via Lambda, I'm getting this connection error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at Connection._handleConnectTimeout 
(/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:412:13)
```

I have configured the Lambda function as such:

```
- No VPC
- Role:  "Basic with DynamoDB" (a tutorial mentioned using this)
```

The RDS database has a public URL and as in a security group that allows inbound connections to port 3306 from any host.  I can connect to it from my laptop successfully and run queries.

Any recommendations on how my Lambda can connect to the MySQL DB?
I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: show me node.js code connect to RDS ?

Comment: Provide your code. Are you trying to conencto by ip or name and what your lambda timeout?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a security group issue for me. Enabled connection from 0.0.0.0/0 for the RDS security group to fix it.